# How to find the ratio of two numbers written in scientific notation, such as $ 2.69 \cdot 10^{-8} $ and $ 2.23 \cdot 10^{-7} $?

Tags: notation, physics, ratio, floating-point

The numbers are forces and he wants us to put them in a ratio in order to compare them, but I'm really bad at ratios so.

$ 2.69 \cdot 10^{-8} $ Newtons is obviously smaller than $ 2.23 \cdot 10^{-7} $ Newtons, but how can that be expressed in a ratio?

Comment: $\left(2.69 \cdot 10^{-8}\right)/\left(2.23 \cdot 10^{-7}\right)$?

Comment: Is it really that simple?

Comment: If you want a ratio, why not just divide?

Comment: The scientific notation scared me I guess. I've never been good at math like that, I don't really understand why I chose physics instead of chemistry.

Comment: Except that it is obviously smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted it.

Comment: $\frac{0.0000000269}{0.000000223}$ = $\frac{269}{2230}$

Answer (score 1):

Making this an answer: You would do the same thing with scientific notation that you would do with integers or any other reals. $$ \dfrac {a \cdot 10^p}{b \cdot 10^q} = \dfrac {a}{b} \cdot 10^{p-q}. $$Here, we have $$ \dfrac {2.69 \cdot 10^{-8}}{2.23 \cdot 10^{-7}} = \dfrac {2.69}{2.23} \cdot 10^{-1} = \dfrac {269}{2230}. $$